# Get base currency scope in Magento 2 Programmatically

Tags: magento2, price, currency, scope

I have created dynamic rows in Product edit form using dataProvider as per my custom requirements. I want to have Catalog Price Scope dropdown with amount option as in screen shot:
[image]

I have got amount field with currency symbol. 
In dynamic rows children I added:

```
'children' => [

                static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME => $this->getPriceFieldConfigForSelectType(30)

            ]
```

and defined function as:

```
private function getPriceFieldConfigForSelectType(int $sortOrder)
{
    $priceFieldConfig = $this->getPriceFieldConfig($sortOrder);
    $priceFieldConfig['arguments']['data']['config']['template'] = 'Magento_Catalog/form/field';

    return $priceFieldConfig;
}
protected function getPriceFieldConfig($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Amount'),
                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                    'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/js/components/custom-options-component',
                    'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME,
                    'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                    'addbefore' => $this->getCurrencySymbol(),
                    'addbeforePool' => $this->productOptionsPrice->prefixesToOptionArray(),
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    'validation' => [
                        'validate-number' => true
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

I just wanted to know how to add base/catalog Price Scope in Dynamic rows.
Thanks